# pass multiple argumens as single string to external program

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

I want to pass multiple arguments to a bash script as a *single string parameter* to an external executable (especially `git`)

I found several answers that suggest something like this:

```
"'$*'"
"'$@'"
```

which looks pretty good when passing to `echo` but fails when passed to an external programm, even if piped through `echo`.

This is a MWE:

```
#!/bin/bash

# preparation
git init .
git add -A

echo git commit -m "'$@'" # works when copied to terminal
git commit -m "'$@'" # fails if more than one parameter given
git commit -m $(echo "'$@'") # fails if more than one parameter given

rm -rf .git # c
```

reults in:

```
$ bash test.sh test2 test2
empty Git-Repository in /tests/bash-scripts/.git/ initialized
git commit -m 'test1 test2'
error: pathspec 'test2'' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'test2'' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

How do I pass multiple script parameters as a *single string* (including spaces) to an external executable (without wrapping them in `""` in the script call.

---

Just found out that this works:

```
 git commit -m "$(echo "'$@'")"
```

but that leads me to the next level:

I want to ommit the `-m` parameter if no arguments are given so that the commit message editor is triggered:

```
if [ 0 != $# ]
then
  MESSAGE ="-m " "$(echo "'$@'")"
fi
git commit $MESSAGE
```

or

```
if [ 0 != $# ]
then
  MESSAGE =("-m " "$(echo "'$@'")")
fi
echo 
git commit ${MESSAGE[@]}
```

this again fails even wose, the quoted words are also separated.:

```
$bash test.sh "test1 test2" test3
git commit -m 'test1 test2 test3'
error: pathspec 'test2' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'test3'' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to interpret all the arguments as one string, use

```
"$*"
```

i.e.

```
git commit -m "$*"
```

It's documented in `man bash` under "Special Parameters":

> `*` Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.  When  the  expansion  is  not  within double quotes, each positional parameter expands to a
>                 separate word.  In contexts where it is performed, those words are  subject
>                 to  further  word  splitting  and  pathname  expansion.  When the expansion
>                 occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value  of
>                 each  parameter  separated  by the first character of the `IFS` special variable.  That is, `"$*"` is equivalent to `"$1c$2c..."`, where  `c`  is  the  first
>                 character  of  the value of the IFS variable.  If `IFS` is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces.  If `IFS` is null, the  parameters  are  joined
>                 without intervening separators.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it solves the first problem, but not the second after my update.

Comment: `message=(-m "$*")` should work.

Comment: no, it does not `MESSAGE=(-m "$*")` followed by `echo git commit ${MESSAGE[@]}` results in `git commit -m test1 test2 test3` which misses the quotes around the parameters and therefore fails when omitting the `echo`.

Comment: You need to doublequote: `git commit "${message[@]}"`.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle you **really** need to read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes as knowing which type of quotes to use where/when is crucial when writing shell scripts. Also run all of your programs through https://www.shellcheck.net/ until you get more experience.